# How to use the API BitConverter.ToUInt16(ReadOnlySpan<Byte>) Unity3D missing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The API from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.touint16?view=netstandard-2.0 is mising in Unity3D 2020.3.8f1c1.How can I make it work? I need a way to convert Span to ushort for my network model.

Other informatioon
System.Memory.4.5.4 from nuget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity3D can use .netstandard2.0 and import System.Memory dll.I write the code to solve the issue:

```
        public static unsafe ushort ToUInt16(this ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytespan)
    {
        fixed (byte* bp = bytespan)
        {
            return *(ushort*)bp;
        }
    }
```

It looks run ok.

Comment: The perfect solution I want is to extract the BitConverter from the .netcore source code, but I don't know where to get the BitConverter source code.

Comment: Finally,I have found it。https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/BitConverter.cs .All is OK.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the type [`ReadOnlySpan<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.readonlyspan-1) as well as the [`Span<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.span-1) itself do only exist in

- .NET 5.0, 6.0 Preview 3
- .NET Core    2.1, 2.2, 3.0, 3.1
- .NET Standard    2.1

But Unity uses `.NET Framework 4.x` where these types do not exist at all.

So in Unity you can only use the `byte[]` overloads.

---

As an alternative to the `Span` you can use [`ArraySegment<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.arraysegment-1) which works quite similar - yet is a bit more work and not as "secure" as the `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` overloads.

The `ArraySegment` alone is actually pretty "dumb" and nothing more than a simple struct storing the array, an offset and a count. It comes with no own "magic" .. you have to do things "manually" yourself, in particular e.g. update the count when you change the offset (that was the point that bothered me the most ^^)

```
public static ushort ReadUshort(ref ArraySegment<byte> bytes)
{
    var output = BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes.Array, bytes.Offset);

    // shift the segment about the size of a ushort
    bytes = bytes.Shift(sizeof(ushort));

    return output;
}

...

public class ArraySegmentExtensions
{
    public static ArraySegment<T> Shift(this ArraySegment<T> segment, int amount)
    {
        return bytes = new ArraySegment<T> (segment.Array, segment.Offset + amount, segment.Count - amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this is not what I want 